# Write a Macro to pull all table and column names used in SQL Query in excel?

Tags: sql, oracle, macros

I want to write a Macro in excel to pull all the Column Names and Table Names used in SQL Query.

For this i want to put the SQL Query in a Text file or Excel file and then I want to extract all columns and tables used in that SQL using Macro. and I want final result (table and column names) in Excel file.

My database is Oracle.

Comment: you can use MSQuery component to query data dictionary, which will populate your workshee. however, having a table list in excel is not a self-contained task to be solved by marcros, it is something intermediate. what is the high-level problem you're solving?

Comment: @Be here now: I have to extract table and column names from the SQL Query generated by COGNOS Report Studio. I know there are several web based tools available but due to securtiy reasons I can't use those tools. Also I need data in excel only so that i do further processing on that and I found Macro/VB Script is the best ways to do this.

Comment: Not Clear are you saying for some sql Select MyColumn From MyTable, you want to return MyTable and MyColumn? As in parse the sql?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: yes Tony... you got it right!!! Also I want the columns used in Where clause. eg. -----Select MYCOLUMN from MYTABLE where CONCOLUMN = CONDITION------ So i want MYCOLUMN, MYTABLE and CONCOLUMN.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Pity, as the sum total of my knowlege about hexsell is how to spell it. Why do you want this, if you did why in Cthulhu's name would you do it in a work sheet. What about joins, CTEs, Views, Functions, Stored Procs, temporary tables, anonymous joins with aliases. UNless there's some built in function inthe DBMS to do it, this is a mare.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your company policy, If you are able to run certain programs, you Could use sql developer, run your query, and export the result set to an XLS format. That will give you your excel file.